# Create a shell script to run a Java program on Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have created a java program which syncs the contents of two directories. The program takes the location of the two directories as arguments the proceeds to sync them, the sync information is them stored in a JSON formatted file inside each directory. 
I have one referenced library `json-simple-1.1.1.jar`

I'm running this from eclipse on windows and everything is working correctly.
I want to create a shell script so that I can run this on a Linux terminal by typing `sync dir1 dir2` where `sync` is my java program and `dir1` and `dir2` are the paths to the directories to synchronize from the current directory.

I'm very new to shell scripts and Linux and unsure whether this is easy to do or will take me all day.

Comment: Have you heard of rsync?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a file named "sync" in /usr/bin containing the following:

```
java -jar {PATH TO JARFILE} $1 $2
```

Replace `{PATH TO JARFILE}` with the path to the jarfile

Make the file executable by typing `chmod +x sync` while in /usr/bin

Comment: Assuming this is all done on Linux? Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: What file extension should "sync" have?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Yes this is indeed all done on Linux. Because it's been a long time since i've done this myself i don't quite remember what file extension it should have. I think it's no file extension, just plain "sync", if that doesn't work you can also try "sync.sh". It's one of those two

Comment: generally shell scripts are named with ".sh" extension : example script-name.sh

Answer (score 4):

you can create a shell with name say "run.sh" (note .sh extension which tell it is a shell script) and copy it in /usr/local/bin directory.

1.Script (run.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh

arg1=$1
arg2=$2

##directory where jar file is located    
dir=/directory-path/to/jar-file/

##jar file name
jar_name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar

## Permform some validation on input arguments, one example below
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "Missing arguments, exiting.."
        echo "Usage : $0 arg1 arg2"
        exit 1
fi

java -jar $dir/$jar_name arg1 arg2
```

2. copy the script in /usr/local/bin

   cp run.sh /usr/local/bin
3. Give execute permission to the script

   chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/test.sh
4. now you can type just word run or run.sh on command line : shell will auto-complete the script name and also it can executed by pressing enter key.